# Powershell Script stops until keyboard input

Tags: powershell

My Powershell Script stops and needs keyboard input to continue.
In the whole Scrpt there is no User Input cmdlet used. No Console Input get prompted.

```
# QUEUE
for ($Script:procCounter; $Script:procCounter -le $QueueLenght; $Script:procCounter++)
{
    Update-TempIndex
    Update-DestIndex
    "TempIndex: $Script:indexT"
    "DestIndex: $Script:indexD"
    
    Start-PlotProcess -argT $ChiaArgTemp[$Script:indexT] -argD $ChiaArgDest[$Script:indexD]
    
    [bool]$partNotReady = $true
    while ($partNotReady)
    {
        $partReadyLog = Get-Content $Script:currentLog -Tail 1500 | Where-Object { $_ -like "Starting phase 2*" }
        
        if ($partReadyLog -ne $null)
        {
            $partNotReady = $false
            "[$(get-date -f 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')] Check Queue #$Script:procCounter for Phase-Readines, Result: YES"
        }
        else
        {
            "[$(get-date -f 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')] Check Queue #$Script:procCounter for current Phase, Result: NO"
            "[$(get-date -f 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')] Wait 240s to check again.."
            Start-Sleep 240
        }
    }
    
}
```

240s Start-Sleep Delay until 14:37:58. Then the Script "freezes" and only continues when i press a keyboard key.. But why??

OUTPUT

```
[16.05.2021 14:25:58] Start Queue 1 and redirect to C:\chia\Logs\PlotProc_1.log
[16.05.2021 14:25:58] Check Queue #1 for current Phase, Result: NO
[16.05.2021 14:25:58] Wait 240s to check again..
[16.05.2021 14:29:58] Check Queue #1 for current Phase, Result: NO
[16.05.2021 14:29:58] Wait 240s to check again..
[16.05.2021 14:33:58] Check Queue #1 for current Phase, Result: NO
[16.05.2021 14:33:58] Wait 240s to check again..
**[16.05.2021 14:37:58]** Check Queue #1 for current Phase, Result: NO
**[16.05.2021 18:11:34]** Wait 240s to check again..
[16.05.2021 18:15:34] Check Queue #1 for Phase-Readines, Result: YES
```

Environment (Full Patched Windows Server 2019)

```
 $PSVersionTable
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1852
    PSEdition                      Desktop
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
    BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1852
    CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
    WSManStackVersion              3.0
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

    Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem
    SystemDirectory : C:\Windows\system32
    Organization    :
    BuildNumber     : 17763
    RegisteredUser  : Windows User
    Version         : 10.0.17763
```

I did read about Edit Mode.. Does Quick Edit Mode really stop the entire script?

Comment: if something triggers the console - such as a mouse click in the console window - things will stop until there is another click or keypress. take a look at this ... https://content.spiceworksstatic.com/service.community/p/post_images/0000337949/5c0ac553/attached_image/k8EVM.jpg

Comment: +1 for @Lee_Dailey especialy since the delay happens right between two line in the script that do nothing but to write text. This behavior can be seen very well with a `ping -t 127.0.0.1`. Just click in the window and it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

When the QuickEdit Mode/Insert options checkbox are checked, right click at the top of the PowerShell window, and click on window properties, and then afterwards you click on the console, the output will be paused. If those options are not checked, the output cannot be paused when you click in the PowerShell console window.